# How can we interpret $\lim_{\beta l \to \pi/2} \tan (\beta l)$ in the quarter-wave impedance transformer equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, trigonometry, signal-processing

From the theory of [Quarter wave impedance transformer wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-wave_impedance_transformer), it is written
$$
\begin{align*}
 Z_{in} &=\lim_{\beta l \to \pi/2}Z_0\frac{Z_l + j Z_0 \tan (\beta l)}{Z_0 + j Z_l \tan (\beta l)}\\
 &=Z_0\frac{j Z_0 }{ j Z_l}
\end{align*}
$$
Does that mean that 
$$
\lim_{\beta l \to \pi/2} \tan (\beta l) = +\infty
$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align*}
Z_{in} &=\lim_{\beta l \to \pi/2}Z_0\frac{\underbrace{Z_l}_{\text{relatively small}} + j Z_0 \underbrace{\tan (\beta l)}_{\text{relatively big}}}{\underbrace{Z_0}_{\text{relatively small}} + j Z_l \underbrace{\tan (\beta l)}_{\text{relatively big}}}\\
\implies Z_{in} &=Z_0\frac{j Z_0 }{ j Z_l}
\end{align*}
$$
?

Comment: Yes, why not? But why leave the $j$ in both numerator and denominator in the final result? Also, the link is broken I think.

Comment: thank you for the comment @AmitHochman. I fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation is that by adding a quarter wavelength of transmission line to the original load impedance, $Z_l$, it is transformed to its dual impedance $Z_0^2/Z_l$. So, for example, a purely capacitive impedance is transformed into a purely inductive one, and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for the answer